# Abstract number ring of any characteristic

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(n_1,\ldots, n_i,\ldots)$ be an infinite tuple of nonnegative integers. Is there an abstract number ring $D$ of a given characteristic $p>0$ and $I_1,\dots, I_n , \ldots$ its nonzero ideals (by assumption $D/I_i$ are finite) such that #$D/I_i=n_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: Couldn't $D=\mathbb{Z}$, $I_k=k\mathbb{Z}$ for all $k>1$, and the tuple simply be $\mathbb{N}$?  Or am I misunderstanding your notation?

Comment:  What about characteristic $p>0$? The tuple $(n_1,n_2,\ldots)$ is given.

Comment: Your question is written in the wrong order. You don't want to first introduce the ring and its ideals, and only then bring in the numbers $n_i$, but rather *first* introduce a sequence of positive integers $n_1, n_2,\dots$ and then ask if there is a $D$ with its ideals enumerable as $I_1, I_2,\dots$ such that $D/I_i$ has size $n_i$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by an abstract number ring; nevertheless, here's an attermpt at an answer.  If $D$ is to have characteristic $p$, then each of the quotients $D/I_i$ will be a vector space over $\mathbb Z/p$, so each $n_i$ will have to be a power of $p$.  Conversely, if all the $n_i$ are powers of $p$, say $n_i=p^{k_i}$, then you could take $D$ to be the polynomial ring $(\mathbb Z/p)[X]$ and take $I_i$ to be the ideal generated by $X^{k_i}$.

Comment: Is it true that the $I_k$ must be necessarily be all of the distinct ideals of $D$?  If so the $n_k$ would have to have appropriate multiplicities for the $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ example.

Comment: @lemniscate: I got the point, which answers my question in the negative.

Comment: Just regarding the point 'abstract number ring' this merely means that the quotient by any ideal is finite (and some nondegeneracy condition, not a field and infinite). Pete Clark seems to lieke them http://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/aant.pdf